# How to use Spring.Net with Silverlight-enabled WCF Services?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, spring.net

I wanna use Spring.Net with a Silverlight-enabled WCF Services. I created a service "User.svc" and configured it to work with Spring.Net, I got these errors:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ```
> Composition proxy target must implement at least one interface. 
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> ```
>
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> ```
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Composition proxy target must implement at least one interface.
>
> Source Error: 
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
> ```
>
> the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Could you give me a hand on this? All related files are listed below.

User.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Client.Web.WCFServices.User" CodeBehind="User.svc.cs" Factory="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"  %>
```

User.svc.cs

```
[SilverlightFaultBehavior]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Client.Web")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class User
{
    private string testdi = "abc";

[OperationContract]
    public string Hello(string msg)
    {
        return msg;
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public int GetUserFromFingerprint(string fpt)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public string HelloSpring(string msg)
    {
        UserDao ud = new UserDao();
        Entities.User u = new Entities.User();
        u.Password = "abc";
        u.Group = new Entities.Group();
        ud.Save(u);
        return this.testdi;
    }
}
```

Spring.net config file

```
<object id="UserServiceHost" type="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactoryObject, Spring.Services">
    <property name="TargetName" value="UserService" />
</object>
<object id="UserService" singleton="false" type="Client.Web.WCFServices.User, Client.Web">
    <property name="testdi" value="qwe" />
</object>
```

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="Client.Web.WCFServices.User.customBinding0">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
                               multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="UserService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Client.Web.WCFServices.User.customBinding0"
                      contract="Client.Web.WCFServices.User" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to Spring.Net or Silverlight.

WCF uses contracts implemented as interfaces. You do not have interface.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISampleInterface
{
// No data contract is requred since both the parameter 
// and return types are primitive types.
[OperationContract]
double SquareRoot(int root);

// No Data Contract required because both parameter and return 
// types are marked with the SerializableAttribute attribute.
[OperationContract]
System.Drawing.Bitmap GetPicture(System.Uri pictureUri);

// The MyTypes.PurchaseOrder is a complex type, and thus 
// requires a data contract.
[OperationContract]
bool ApprovePurchaseOrder(MyTypes.PurchaseOrder po);
}
```

Note the ServiceContract and OperationContract are on the interface, not on the class that implements the interface.

Comment: hi,I tried your solution but it doesn't help. And if I remove the line "Factory="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"" in User.svc.cs (Put this service out of control of Spring.Net), no error reported.